# Reading result from TFDUpdateSQL in OnUpdateRecord event

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have setup a simple TFDQuery that is tied to TFDUpdateSQL Component to handle updates.
The TFDUpdateSQL Insert sql inserts a row in to a table and after that calls scope_Indetity to get the latest Identity insert value. I want to read this value in the OnUpdateRecord event handler . I am trying to read it using the TFDUpdateSQl.Dataset.Fields[0].Asinteger but this returns 0 as value eerytime. Can someone help me understand how i can read results of insert in OnUpdateRecord.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What database are you using? Could you edit your question and add a minimal complete and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can test?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `OnNewRecord` for insert, `OnUpdateRecord` for Edit/Update.
It depends on how you are working with DB and how the Identity is created/added.
Maybe you will need to use `AfterPost`.

Comment: We do not use signatures here. Your identity is available in the lower right corner of every question or answer you post. It's also not necessary to use HTML to end lines - a simple press of the Enter key works just fine.

Comment: Enter is not working. If You give two time Enter there will be additional line ;-( if you use html - its working.

Comment: Enter works fine, and has for more than a decade. It seems to work for everyone but you. :-) HTML breaks formatting sometimes, and most HTML is not accepted outside a code block. You can see that there was no HTML required in your post, because I removed it when I made my edit - the site's wordwrap did all the work. If you need a new paragraph, one Enter provides it. Two Enters gives you a blank line between the paragraphs.

Comment: and its not like I made it. Its one line text ;-( after you change it.